# How to configure Firestore end-points at run-time?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have developed an Android APP based on Firestore for DB storing data.

Now I need that the user is able to configure on the APP at run-time the end-point of Firestore DB - these parameters are typically stored in google-services.json (firebase_url, project_id, storage_bucket)

How can these values be changed at run time? Is there a specific Android API to do this?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion/support on this matter :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to take control of the initialization of your app, rather than allow the default initialization.  This is kind of complicated, and it involves calling [FirebaseApp.initializeApp()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp.html#initializeApp(android.content.Context,%20com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions)) correctly with the details of the project you're trying to access.

I've written a couple blogs about this:

- https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/how-does-firebase-initialize-on-android.html
- https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/take-control-of-your-firebase-init-on.html